Kevin Bacon as radio presenter: wristwatch brand
There is a movie starring Kevin Bacon in which he works as a radio presenter (or DJ?) at a local radio. Between consecutive songs he occasionally live-reads an ad. There is an ad about a (fictional) wristwatch, called something like "Brue-N". I'd like to know the title of the movie, and -- especially -- the exact brand name of this wristwatch. Thanks!
(AFAIR the wristwatch brand has nothing to do with the plot. There is a special reason why I'd like to know it.)

If you're sure it's Kevin Bacon, have you at least checked his filmography? That being said, Telling Lies in America has him as a radio DJ.

@NapoleonWilson That's it, thanks! I've found subtitles - the wristwatch is called "Gruen".

It turned out that there was a "Gruen Watch Company": http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gruen_Watch_Co. So the brand name is not fictional, as I believed.

A movie that features Kevin Bacon as a radio DJ would be Telling Lies in America:

Karchy (Brad Renfro) is a boy in school who has moved from Hungary to America in the 1960's. He is struggling in school and trying to adjust to America's culture. He then hears about a radio DJ Billy Magic (Kevin Bacon) who holds a contest for a Student Hall of Fame every week. When Karchy finally wins after several weeks, he spends more time with Billy Magic...a man with money, girls, and glam. Karchy thinks that by spending time with Magic, he can become "cool". He then starts telling lies, to make himself seem greater than he really is. But when his lies begin hurting the people he cares about, he realizes that it isn't worth telling lies if it affects your friends. Afterwards, he learns to accept himself for the person he is, and gives up lying. And as for Billy Magic, it turns out that he pays his price for all the lies that he has told as well....

I have however nothing else to support this other than the fact that Kevin Bacon plays a radio DJ in it (as I haven't seen the movie at all, only found it by a 2-minute check of his filmography) and the fact that the asker confirmed it's the correct movie in a comment.
